# Get motion data for minut sensor using C#

Tags: c#

I have an issue with getting only the motion sensor data using the minut Api, I try follow this documentation: [https://api.minut.com/latest/docs#tag/Devices/paths/~1devices~1{device_id}~1motion_events/get](https://api.minut.com/latest/docs#tag/Devices/paths/%7E1devices%7E1%7Bdevice_id%7D%7E1motion_events/get)
and I got an error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'SensorReading+API_CustomEntity' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '[0]', line 2, position 3.'
```

The error happens in this line of codes (the motion events), the rest of the codes there is no error:

```
List<SensorReading.API_CustomEntity> SoundLevelReadings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SensorReading.API_CustomEntity>>(DeserializeAPIObj(SOUNDLEVEL));
            List<SensorReading.API_CustomEntity> TemperatureReadings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SensorReading.API_CustomEntity>>(DeserializeAPIObj(TEMPERATURE));
            List<SensorReading.API_CustomEntity> HumidityReadings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SensorReading.API_CustomEntity>>(DeserializeAPIObj(HUMIDITY));
            List<SensorReading.API_CustomEntity> MotionEventsReadings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SensorReading.API_CustomEntity>>(DeserializeAPIObj(MOTIONEVENTS));
```

Comment: Seems you're trying to deserialize an already deserialized object.  Whats the signature of the  DeserializeAPIObj function

Comment: even if i remove that, it will still show the same error tho

Comment: 'DeserializeAPIObj(SOUNDLEVEL)' must be a String hence my question

Comment: protected string DeserializeAPIObj(string APIObj)
        {
      

            dynamic resp = JObject.Parse(APIObj);
            string deserialize = resp.values.ToString();
            return deserialize;
        }

Comment: for motion i also put static same as the sound level

Comment: seems that `resp.values.ToString()` didn't produce a valid json string

Comment: hmm, the rest of the data works tho, just only the motion does not work